# Spring cascade field not updated

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I have an object with the following attribute but when I try to save the object this field is not merging.
How can I solve the issue ?

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "userSites", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotAudited
private List<IUser> localIt;
```

userSites:

```
@BatchSize(size = 20)
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Site.class)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_SITE",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = USER_ID, nullable = false) },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SITE_ID", nullable = false) })
private Set<ISite> userSites;
```

Comment: Where is the Jointable annotation attribute?

Comment: @MasterMind Why should I use it ? this is mapped with userSites that refer to a table in database. I edited my post to see the field

Comment: And the first one is  in Site class

Comment: @MasterMind the first is in Site class and the second in the User class

Comment: It does not save the sites  when you are persisting a User ?

Comment: @MasterMind With the code below, it save the site and I don't have any error message but the db is not updated and the user is not persisted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78533/discussion-between-master-mind-and-jerome-campeaux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of save the attribute :

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "userSites", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotAudited
private List<IUser> localIt;
```

I updated the site list of each users by adding the site to register into the concerned field :

```
@BatchSize(size = 20)
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Site.class)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_SITE",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = USER_ID, nullable = false) },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SITE_ID", nullable = false) })
private Set<ISite> userSites;
```